# Извлечь данные combobox item

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть Combobox в нем есть ComboBoxItem, помимо Content можно как то вытащить другие данные например DataContext, а затем присвоить переменной [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте привязки и не будет этих проблем...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да это я знаю что можно использовать привязки. Но я хочу узнать можно ли делать так как описал выше

Comment: если нету такого способа, то опубликуйте минимальный код для привязки

Comment: `Можно ли` - я считаю нет. WPF не любит такое, это не WinForms. Если вы не используете привязки, то вам WPF вообще нет смысла использовать! `Возможно ли` - естественно. Просто приведите (что надо) к `ComboBoxItem` и получите полный доступ к его свойствам. Например вот вам ответ с [EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2961144/6808809).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно, можно:

```
foreach (ComboBoxItem item in comboBox1.Items)
{
    var x = item.DataContext;
    //...
}
```

Только зачем присваивать свойству DataContext какие-то строки? Обычно свойству DataContext присваивается объект для привязки, и не на уровне ComboBoxItem, а на уровне элемента управления или окна в целом. Если вам нужно хранить произвольные данные в ComboBoxItem, используйте свойство [Tag](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_FrameworkElement_Tag).